# Every Polish space is the image of the Baire space by a continuous and closed map, reference

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

The following result was originally proven by Engelking in his 1969 paper [**On closed images of the space of irrationals**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2036424) ([AMS](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-021-03/S0002-9939-1969-0239571-X/), [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2036424), [MR239571](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=239571), [Zbl 0177.25501](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0177.25501))

> Every Polish space (i.e. every separable completely metrizable space) is the image of the Baire space $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ by a continuous and closed map.

I was surprised not to find this result (even disguised as an exercise) in Kechris' *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*, since it feels like a standard result in descriptive set theory.  I would like to know if there is a (relatively) recent book or general treatise that contains this result.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked Kechris 7.9 Theorem?

Comment: @Burak, yes. The continuous surjection he builds is bijective, but (therefore) not closed in general.

Comment: @Burak [Exercise 7.14](https://books.google.com/books?id=WR3SBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA40) is about every non-empty Polish space being an *open* image of the Baire space. Kechris mentions the result about closed image - but without a proof: "In R. Engelking [1969] it is shown that X can also be obtained as a continuous and closed image of $\mathcal N$."